# Disable sound effects in a RecyclerView when swithcing between items using D-PAD

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv, d-pad

I want to disable the annoying sound effects when switching between items in a RecyclerView with a D-PAD and just get rid of them if possible in the whole application.

I tried setting

```
  <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
```

in the main AppTheme and also tried setting this property in each item of the recyclerview but it did NOT work.

I also tried setting this in OnResume

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
} else {
    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
}
```

which worked in most devices that does not have the `isVolumeFixed()` in AudioManager set to true which is the case with Amazon FireTV.

If the volume is fixed it means that I cannot adjust the volume of any stream, is there a workaround to disable the sound effects in this case?

I was using a ListView previously and the sound effects where disabled just fine when I set soundEffectsEnabled to false, but I'm  not sure why it isn't working with RecyclerView.